# NLopt library import in Eclipse Phortran

Tags: eclipse, fortran, nlopt

I'm programming Fortran 2008 using Eclipse Phortran. I need to implement the NLopt optimizer and downloaded [NLopt for Windows (64bit)](http://nlopt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/NLopt_on_Windows/).

Unfortunately, I'm not able to get the library import running even after searching this and other forums.

I have following files prepared for Windows provided by NLopt:
[Files from NLopt download](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mw1c4.png)

Which files do I have to link in Eclipse? As I have found out in other threads, I have to implement the library and the path in here:
[Eclipse library linker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlJNw.png)
However, nothing I tried so far is working.
It would be very nice, if you could provide me a small tutorial.

Comment: When you say nothing is working, what happens? Any error messages?

Comment: Hello Vladimir,

Comment: Did you want to tell us something? [Edit] the question if you have some important information.